# What's the purpose of *(id*)obj?

Tags: objective-c, ios

```
typedef struct _wax_instance_userdata {
    id instance;
    BOOL isClass;
    Class isSuper; 
    BOOL actAsSuper; 
} wax_instance_userdata;
```

https://github.com/probablycorey/wax/blob/master/lib/wax_helpers.m#L497

```
void* afunc(){ // the function is too long
    void *value = nil;
    // ...
    wax_instance_userdata *instanceUserdata = (wax_instance_userdata *)luaL_checkudata(L, stackIndex, WAX_INSTANCE_METATABLE_NAME);

    instance = instanceUserdata->instance;

    *(id *)value = instance;
    return value;
}
```

https://github.com/probablycorey/wax/blob/master/lib/wax.m#L243

```
id* ret = afunc(); //same without this * .
id lastValue = *(id*)ret;
//now I can use lastValue;
```

Why need do this ? 
I can't understand the `*(id*)`
also the `id* ret = afunc()` ,when delete this star , it also works well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

afunc is referencing the function (void *)wax_copyToObjc(...). The intent of this function is to translate a Lua object into a C or Objective-C value. Because it could be a primitive type or an objective-c instance it doesn't know what it is going to return. So always returns a pointer to void (meaning a pointer to something unknown). In the case of an id, it will return a pointer to an id.

It might be easier to explain what is happening with an int, it will alloc space for the int and copy the its value:

```
value = calloc(sizeof(int), 1)
*(int *)value = lua_tointeger(L, stackIndex)
```

(int *)value is translates to "value is a pointer to an int"
adding the *  in front of it like `*(int *)value` translates to "copy the int to the alloc'd memory that value points to."

In your example:

```
id *ret = afunc(); // returns a pointer to an id
id lastValue = *(id*)ret; // dereferences the pointer to id so it is just an id
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks weird. Since the issues came from what looks like C Code, I suggest to not use `id`. Although it's supposed to be the same as `void*`, devs tend to use the first in ObjC code, and the latter in C code. You'd gain in clarity.

Now, I don't see why `void* value = instance;` and `void* ret = afunc();` should not do as expected.

Comment: https://github.com/probablycorey/wax/blob/master/lib/wax_helpers.m#L497    (line 497)  https://github.com/probablycorey/wax/blob/master/lib/wax.m#L243 (line 243)

Comment: There's no `id` in plain C so the code obviously is Objective-C.

Comment: I know. What I meant was that usually, in C fragments, people tend to discard `id` in favor of `void*`, for coherence. What I missed though, is that this is not his own code. Next time I'll spend more time reading the original question.